# Is there a way in Java to simulate something similar to declaring object type as a variable inside a class?

Tags: java, generics

Lets say I have 1000 business services that are almost identical with only the Entity name and data return object that are different.  Lets presume here that its not possible or desirable to have a generic class with generics passed in due to some potential variation and ability to make specific changes to each class in the future.  These need to be separate classes.

Is there a way to declare (or simulate declaration) of object types?

For example, I would like to have a get like this.   Where MyDeclaredDTOType and MyDeclaredEntityType are not actual objects, just the local named that are declared for actual objects.

```
public MyDeclaredDTOType getMyDTO(Long id){

   MyDeclaredEntityType entity = myRepository.getById(id);

   return entity.toDTO();
}
```

If this is not possible what is the closest solution in java for this type of a problem?   If generics are used how would the method above look?

Comment: What you are describing would be Generics. I'm not sure why you can't use them or don't want to but if you really need to create 1000 different services, have a look at code generators that use a template and create the classes for you.

Comment: As @Thomas already said: think about code generation of some kind!

Comment: You said the primary problem driving this is due to security concerns.  Perhaps the focus should be given to mitigating those concerns in other ways.  For instance, would the Java security manager be of use?   Consider also that someone else may have to maintain or modify those classes in the future.  I added a security tag to get additional focus on the problem.

Comment: @WJS I agree on addressing the security concerns. Just note that Security Manager is meant to be deprecated in Java 17 and likely to be removed in subsequent versions.

Comment: @Thomas  I did not know that. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @WJS I just stumbled across this when reading about the new features of Java 17 :) - Here's the JEP for reference: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/411

Comment: I don't quite see how not allowing generic would mitigate a certain security concern.

Comment: I'm not really sure how the security topic started here.  It was just in a list of hypothetical reasons that would require you to not have a generic class for everything but needing to have multiple similar classes.   There are no security concerns.  Only concerns of having many almost the same classes and having to change the names of objects manually in all the methods vs once on top of each class.   Generics may end up being the best solution, however it seems to me that generics are there to accomplish an opposite scenario.

Answer (score 1):

No, java does not have a built in meta-programming system (C's `#define` and friends, that's meta programming).

Java does have annotation processors which can generate source files as part of the compilation process, and then those source files are themselves also compiled. Thus, you could make one that emits a thousand java files.

Note that having a thousand classes, all slightly different, is **highly** suboptimal. You're really jumping through hoops here and causing all sorts of nasty side-effects (just loading in those 1000 and keeping them in memory is a bit of a cost already, it'll permanently slow down your compilation process, etc) - the right answer is probably to do something about this seemingly bizarre rule that generics cannot be used here.

Writing such a processor isn't exactly easy, but there are plenty of tutorials. Note that you don't need an actual annotated class to 'trigger' your processor to go do the work of making the one thousand source files. I estimate you need one person working about a week, starting with an annotation processor tutorial to get familiar with it all, and ending with one that generates files for you.

There are some tricks to apply here, as well: You'd want to use the filer to check for the existence of the class file in the 'output' in order to save considerable time by not generating the source file (and thus requiring that the compiler compile it) **every time** you build the project, that way.